# Android TextView in an ImageView in a HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, textview, imageview, android-relativelayout, horizontalscrollview

I have a little problem with my layouts. I want put a TextView in an ImageView, but I don't known the size of this image. I want just that the height of the image don't exceed 115dp (I have add a property maxHeight) ; Android adjust the width dynamically.
This text must be written at the bottom of the image and if there is not enough space, it must be cut in multiples lines.
This is working perfectly :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/elem_event_favoris_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:maxHeight="115dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/bg_tmp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/elem_event_favoris_image"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/elem_event_favoris_image"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/elem_event_favoris_image"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/elem_event_favoris_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:background="#55000000"
            android:paddingLeft="3dp"
            android:paddingRight="3dp"
            android:textColor="#EEEEEE" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Example :
[image: Little text]
[image: Long text]

The problem is I must put this layout repeatedly in a HorizontalScrollView :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_events_proximite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RelativeLayout ...>
                <!-- My layout : My little text -->
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout ...>
                <!-- My layout : My very very long text -->
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

And the horizontal scroll has broken my multiples lines split if the text is too large to remain in one line :
[image: HorizontalScrollView]

Have you an idea for solve my problem ? How can I cancel the scroll of the HorizontalScrollView in my RelativeLayout ?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you use horizontal SCROLL view if you do not want scrolling?

Comment: You can do the oppsite: put the image inside the TextView. It's called a compound drawable. Just set the image in the `android:dawableTop`  attribute of the TextView

Comment: Boris: I want scroll on all my elements in my ScrollView, but not scroll the text in an element. If I have for example 5 images, I can't all view on my screen, so I must to scroll.

Comment: Bob: Yes, I can for this example, but I must also create an another same layout, with 2 TextView in the image (one in the bottom, and one in the top-right). So I must create distinctly a ImageView and a TextView, and an another TextView if I need.

Comment: So... by using a RelativeLayout as a container, you can superimpose/overlay its children controls one over another

Comment: Yes, and this is that I make, it works. But if I put this in a HorizontalScrollView, it doesn't work perfectly as you can see in my last screenshot.